# A question about limsup and limif

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you please help me understand this question:

Suppose $a_n$ is bounded sequence and $A<\liminf a_n$, $B>\limsup a_n$.
Prove : $A<a_n<B$ for all n>N.

It seems to me to simple to be true: 
since $A<\liminf a_n\le a_n\le \limsup a_n<B$ therefore $A<a_n<B$.

What I am missing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: What about $a_n=\frac{(-1))^n}{n}$, $A=-0.01$, $B=0.01$? We have $A<\liminf a_n=0=\limsup a_n<B$ and yet $A<a_n<B$ does not hold for $n<100$??

Comment: I edited my post: in this question it sufficient that statement $A<a_n<B$ holds for all n>N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $s_k = sup\{a_n: n\geq k\}$, and let $s = \lim supa_n$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}s_k = s$. Since $s < B$, there exists natural number $m$ such that: if $k > m$ then $s_k < B$. In particular, $s_{m+1} < B$. But $s_{m+1} = sup\{a_n: n\geq m + 1\}$. So: $a_k \leq s_{m+1} < B$ for all $k \geq m + 1$ that is: $a_k < B$ for all $k \geq m + 1$. And for showing that $A < a_n$, we simply observe that $liminfa_n = -limsup(-a_n)$. This means: there exists a natural number $p$ such that: $-a_k < -A$ when $k \geq p + 1$. Then $A < a_k$ when $k \geq p + 1$. Now choose $q = max\{m,p\} + 1$, then we have: $A < a_k < B$ when $k \geq q$.
Done.